# How to Generate a Single file from multiple tables in Informatica Power Center

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to Generate a Single file from multiple tables in Informatica Power Center like below...

[image]

Comment: Qn - how can i identify row1, row2, row3 in each file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this using `UNION ALL`.
Assuming 3 files are read from different sources,

1. Create three expression transformations with 3 ports. This is Exp1, 2, and 3 in below pic. For Exp1-
   `out_concat_all` = Name1 ||'|'||FirstName1||'|'||... and so on.
   `in_NEXTVAL` = Add NEXTVAL from new sequence generator.
   `out_SEQ` = 'File1`||in_NEXTVAL
   Pls make similar logic as per file2 and file3.
2. Create a UNION ALL to combine above 3 pipelines into one pipeline.
3. Sort the data based on SEQ column.
4. Link only concat_all column into a target file .
   Whole flow should look like this -

[image]